# regsub in Tcl to replace pattern with the empty string

Tags: tcl

I need some help in replacing a pattern in TCL.

```
set msg "<sytem>
         <log>
             <test>
                <ggg>yyy</ggg>
             </test>
          </log>
     </sytem>
     one
     two
     three"
set res [regsub -all "<sytem(\>)+" $msg " " test]

puts $test
```

test should contain

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: If you want to remove all the XML, a regex is `{<.+>}`

Comment: And then, to normalize the spaces, `regsub -all {\s+} [string trim $test] "\n" test`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to remove here, but to strip out everything up to the last `>` in the string, you use this:

```
# Greedily matches everything up to the *last* ‘>’ and replaces it with the empty string
# No special quoting required; ‘>’ is not an RE metacharacter
set res [regsub {.*>} $msg ""]
```

Then you can normalize the result in various ways. This might be good enough, if what follows is some simple words:

```
set res [join $res "\n"]
```

Otherwise, you'd need to do this more complicated version:

```
set res [join [lmap [split [string trim $res] "\n"] x {string trim $x}] "\n"]
```

There are other ways of writing it too that are even trickier:

```
set res [regexp -inline -all -line {\S(?:.*\S)} $res]
```